# How to get the derivative approximation from given range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to generate the approximation derivation for a given array.

I have developed an array but don't know how to loop over each value to get derivation

```py
# display the approximation for each delta step in this cell
import numpy as np

delta = (
    np.logspace(-1, -14, 14),
    np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(float="{:10.8e}".format)),
)
print(delta)


def my_derivative_approximation(f, x, d=10e-6):
    return (f(x + d) - f(x)) / d


# Trying to apply approximation derivation to each delta array value

print(my_derivative_approximation(delta, 14))
```

Looking forward to learning this concept.

Comment: what is `(f(x + d) - f(x)) / d`? is `f` a function or simple multiplication?

Comment: @Shijith it's a function derivation

Comment: you are having difficulties with looping over an array? or something else

Comment: Difficulties with looping over an array

Comment: your `delta` is tuple, with first element an array which can be accesses by `delta[0]`. if you want to iterate over each element of the array use `enumerate` so the you can use both index of each array element and its value e.g, `for idx, val in enumerate(delta[0]):`

Comment: Your derivative assumes a continuous function, but your array is a discrete function. What exactly is it you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Nils Werner - I just figured it out that I was trying to get continuous function. Thank you all for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the approximation derivation. In your code, you try to use your numpy array as a function but it is a little bit nonsense. If you want to approximate derivation, you can simply create a function like this :

```
def myFunction(x):
    return x*2
```

After creating this function,  you can create many delta values in delta array :

```
delta = np.logspace(-1, -14, 
14),np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(float='{:10.8e}'.format))
# This is a tuple and you can obtain numpy array that includes delta values by #delta[0]
```

After that, you can iterate over your numpy array by sending your array to a approximation function:

```
# display the approximation for each delta step in this cell
import numpy as np
def myFunction(x):
    return x*2

delta = np.logspace(-1, -14, 
14),np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(float='{:10.8e}'.format))

def my_derivative_approximation(f, x, delta):
    return (f(x + delta) - f(x)) / delta 
#Trying to apply approximation derivation to each delta array value 
print(my_derivative_approximation(myFunction,14,delta[0]))
```

Comment: The `np.vectorize()` wrap is entirely unecessary. First, `myFunction()` is already vectorized, secondly, you're evaluating it for a scalar value anyways. `print(my_derivative_approximation(myFunction,14,delta[0]))` works just as well.